# I cannot delete a 'trigger' assigned to the key 'enter'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little problem. I've used the method `trigger` of jQuery to launch the event `click` on a button when pressed key <kbd>Enter</kbd>. I need to delete that trigger (in the future, pressing key <kbd>Enter</kbd>, don't trigger the event `click` on the button).
This is the code:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 13) $('#thebutton').trigger('click');
});
```

Is it possible? thanks.

Hi, im editing my post after found the solution.
My entire problem was this:

```
$('#thebutton').on('click', function(){
     alert('click on the button');
  });

$(document).on('keyup',function(e){
     if (e.keyCode == 13) $('#thebutton').trigger('click');

// This cause a loop of alert() popups pressing key 'enter'
// Alex fix it in this way:

$('#thebutton').on('click', function(){
        alert('hi there');
});

    var someContition = false;
    $(document).on('keypress',function(e){
        if (e.keyCode == 13  && !someContition) $('#thebutton').trigger('click');
```

The secret is to change `keyup` by `keypress`. Testing the code i found it isnt necessary the flag.
Thanks all of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use keypress instead. Try this **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/AYONaxAW/1/edit)**:

```
var someContition = false; 
$(document).on('keypress',function(e){
 if (e.keyCode == 13  && !someContition) $('#thebutton').trigger('click');
});

$('#thebutton').on('click', function(){
 alert('hi there');
});
```

Comment: Thank alex. I dont want unbind the event 'click' on the button. I just need the key 'enter' dont launch it. i dont know if it's posible.

Comment: What would be the condition why you wouldn't?

Comment: @toniet, I have modified my answer. Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Hi alex. Good solution but is partial for my complete problem.

Comment: What is your complete problem?

Comment: Hi alex. Good solution but is partial for my complete problem. the button launch an alert window. when i close the popup with key enter, i want not to launch 'click' on the button (we fall into a loop of popups with key 'enter), but only at this point. After closed the popup i'd wish the key 'enter' trigger again the 'click' on the button. Your code works fine, the first time. After close the alert popup, key enter dont work. I've used many strategies but dont achieve my porpose. thanks a lot.

Comment: When you say alert window, do you mean just alert(), or window.open() ?

Comment: sorry, an alert() window. I tried you solution and can close the popup whith the key an dont fall into the loop of popups (pressing key enter). After the popup is closed i need activate again the key to launch the 'click' on the button. it's more difficul than seems (for me). The secuence i wish is simple: key enter 1: open popup. key enter 2: close popup. key enter 3: open popup. key enter 4: close popup, and so on. thanks.

Comment: Ahh ok, I got it. I will modify my answer and provide a demo. Once min

Comment: Ok, see my solution above. Let me know if this what you want?

Comment: Glad that you found my answer useful. If you accept my answer please click on the star/checkbox next to my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Of course. I think you refer to the checkbox that turns green and means i 'accept' this answer. Done!

Answer (score 0):

As previously mentioned use `on()` and `off()` but not on the click event. Instead on the keyup because thats what you actually wanna remove.

```
$(document).on('keyup',function(e){
   if (e.keyCode == 13) $('#thebutton').trigger('click');
});
```

And then later

```
$(document).off('keyup');
```

If you still need the keyup event (e.g. for other keys) you will have to set a flag or something and check for it before you trigger the button click.

Answer (score 0):

This may sound stupid, but just comment or erase that line:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e){
    //if (e.keyCode == 13) $('#thebutton').trigger('click');  //Comment or delete this line
});
```

(If you don't have control over this code, you should specifiy it in the question, if that's the case: silly answer to silly question, if not, just ignore this ;) ).

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the HTML :**

```
<input type="button" id="clickme" value="cick me "/>
```

**Here is the jquery:**

```
 $(document).on('keyup',function(e){
     if (e.keyCode == 13) $('#clickme').trigger('click');
  });
  $('#clickme').click(function(){
      alert('i was clicked !');
  });
```

here is the live example : http://jsfiddle.net/tB66Y/